# Creating a Extension Method for a DataGrid => AutoScroll?

Tags: c#, datagrid, extension-methods

I am currently workin on an extensionmethod for the WPF DataGrid.
Here's what I got so far:

```
public static void AutoScrollToEnd(this DataGrid dataGrid)
    {
        if (dataGrid.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, childIndex: 0) as Decorator;
            if (border != null)
            {
                var scroll = border.Child as ScrollViewer;
                if (scroll != null) scroll.ScrollToEnd();
            }
        }
    }
```

VS is giving me an error here:

> var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(**dataGrid**, childIndex: 0) as
>   Decorator;
>
> " Argument type 'System.Windows.Controls.DataGrid' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Windows.DependencyObject' "

Can anyone please explain what the problem is and how to solve it ?

Comment: Are you sure this is the exact error message you get? There is a typo in "System.Widnows". Windows is spelled wrong. If this is the exact error message then you're probably working with some other class `DataGrid` which isn't a `DependencyObject`

Comment: It's the right one ^^   unfortunately it was just a lag or something in VS. I just restarted my laptop and now the error is gone ... ty anyways.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
if (dataGrid.Items.Count > 0)
        {
            var border = VisualTreeHelper.GetChild(dataGrid, childIndex: 0) as ScrollViewer;
            if (border != null)
            {
                border.ScrollToEnd();
            }
        }
```